# How to Deactivate a LDAP User?

Tags: security, authentication, ldap

I am using a library to authenticate LDAP Users, whose code is as follows:

```
public void authUser(String username, String pwd)
    throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      Properties env = getEnvironmentForContext();

      env.put("java.naming.security.principal", "uid=" + 
      username + ",ou=users, dc=company"));
      env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", pwd);
      context = getContext(env);
      System.out.println("Authentication Succeeded");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Authentication Failed");
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Please note, i cannot modify the above Authentication Code. It comes from a external Library.

But, i want to deactivate some users (not delete them), so that Authentication Fails. 
I am using LDAP (not Active Directory). Do not know what LDAP Software it is though, i can connect to it using 'LDAP Browser Client'.

The users exist under: dc=company, ou=users, uid=username

**What attribute can i add/change on LDAP 'user' to de-activate a user.**
Could i move the user to a different group like: dc=company, ou=deactivatedusers, uid=username? But this is not the preferred option, plus am not sure best way to do that.

EDIT: The LDAP being used is: Netscape/Sun/iPlanet

Comment: It would really help if you could tell what type of directory client you're connecting to. The attribute that disables\enables a user can be very different from vendor to vendor. If you use Softerra's free LDAP Browser [found here](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm) to connect, in the "Profile" tab, does it list a directory "Type"?

Comment: Yes it says: Netscape/Sun/iPlanet - Thats the LDAP being used.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question per the Oracle iPlanet (Sun) documentation :

> Setting the attribute `nsAccountLock` to `true` will disable a users account, and prevent them from binding to the directory.

However, in terms of the code you already have, I just don't see any way of accomplishing this... Is there something preventing you from writing your own implementation for iPlanet using the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace in .Net?

Here is how I bind and authorize users against an iPlanet server :

```
//Build servername from variables
var BuildServerName = new StringBuilder();
BuildServerName.Append(ServerName);
BuildServerName.Append(":" + Convert.ToString(Port));

var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(BuildServerName.ToString());
//Authenticate the Admin username and password, making sure it's a valid login

try
{
    //Pass in the network (administrative) creds, and the domain.
    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password, config.LdapAuth.LdapDomain);
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous;;
    ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);

    //Lets find this person so we can use the correct DN syntax when we authorize them.
    SearchRequest FindThem = new SearchRequest();
    FindThem.Filter = config.LdapAuth.LdapFilter.Replace("{{Patron}}", Patron);
    FindThem.DistinguishedName = config.LdapAuth.LdapDomain;
    FindThem.Scope = System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree;

    //We'll execute a search using the bound user
    SearchResponse searchresults = (SearchResponse) ldapConnection.SendRequest(FindThem);

    //Should only get on result back, if not throw an error
    if(searchresults.Entries.Count == 1)
    {
         SearchResultEntryCollection entries = searchresults.Entries;
         SearchResultEntry thispatron = entries[0];
         PatronDN = thispatron.DistinguishedName;
    }
 }
```

If you wanted to move disabled users to a specific group, from this point you could write logic to check the `DistinguishedName` of that user, and throw a handled exception if their `DistinguishedName` contains the name of that group. Also, if the `nsAccountLock` attribute is available to your binding account as a readable attribute, you could just check the value of that attribute for `true`, and handle the user accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the java code for disabling and enabling user in Active Directory using JNDI.
Make sure to connect with your AD before calling below code.

```
    public void disableEnableUser() throws Exception {
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
            //To enable user
            //int UF_ACCOUNT_ENABLE = 0x0001;
            //mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(UF_ACCOUNT_ENABLE)));

        // To disable user
        int UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE = 0x0002;
        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl",Integer.toString(UF_ACCOUNT_DISABLE)));

        ctx.modifyAttributes("CN=John ABC,OU=Users,OU=anyone,DC=yourcompanyname,DC=com", mods);
    }
```

Distinguished name = "CN=John ABC,OU=Users,OU=anyone,DC=yourcompanyname,DC=com"
This name is depend on your structure of Active Directory, you can confirm from your suport team.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the user's password. If it's OpenLDAP with the password-policy overlay, or another LDAP server that supports locking, you can lock the user as well. You really will have to find out.

Comment: This is also an alternative.

Comment: Sorry but this is super stupid. There are many occasions where you will need to threat deactivated account completely differently than activated. It's not only about the fact that the user can't log in...

Comment: @pagep In which case you would delete them, which is specifically excluded in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory software supports a password policy feature, it probably provides attributes to lock/deactivate the user. If not, you can simply nullify the password attribute (e.g., userpassword). The LDAP server should return the "inappropriate authentication" error to the client when the authenticated bind is performed.